# Need to append data to the next blank row instead of creating data in a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to download the historical stock prices from moneycontrol.com. Here is the code I have...the current code extracts data from each webpage and pastes into a new worksheet each time.

But, I would like to append data to the next blank row instead of creating data in a new worksheet. Can someone please help me with this?

```
Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?sc_id=RI&pno={0}&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2015-12-31"
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 1

Sub DataDownload()
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String

    For page = 1 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page)
        Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.[a1])
        queryTableObject.FieldNames = True
        queryTableObject.RowNumbers = False
        queryTableObject.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        queryTableObject.PreserveFormatting = True
        queryTableObject.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        queryTableObject.BackgroundQuery = True
        queryTableObject.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        queryTableObject.SavePassword = False
        queryTableObject.SaveData = False
        queryTableObject.AdjustColumnWidth = False
        queryTableObject.RefreshPeriod = 0
        queryTableObject.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        queryTableObject.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        queryTableObject.WebTables = "4"
        queryTableObject.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        queryTableObject.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        queryTableObject.WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
        queryTableObject.WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        queryTableObject.WebDisableRedirections = True
        queryTableObject.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    Next page

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but try adding this lines:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName") ' change to your actual sheetname
```

Then change this line:

```
Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.[a1])
```

to this line:

```
Set queryTableObject = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URL, _
    Destination:=ws.Range("A:A").Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0))
```

This way, data will be added on the sheet you specified always and at the first blank row.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!I would like the macro to take the sc_id parameter in the url to be taken from '[Data Download.xlsx]DATA'!$B$1.
Could you please help me modify the code??